# Implicit differentiation of $x^y=y^x$, find $y'(x)$ (Boas Chapter 4, Problem 6.3)

Tags: derivatives, calculus

> For $ x^y = y^x, $ find $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ evaluated at the point $(2,4)$.

This is from the popular textbook "Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences" (3rd edition) by Boas. It's in Chapter 4, Section 6, *Implicit differentiation.*

I try following the main text and take $\frac{d}{dx}$ of both sides:

\begin{align}
 x^y & = y^x
\\ x^y & =e^{x\ln y}
\\ yx^{y-1}y' & = \ln y \,e^{x\ln y}\frac{d}{dx}(x\ln y)
\\ yx^{y-1}y' & = y^x\ln y\,(\ln y + \frac{x}{y}y')
\\ yx^{y-1}y' & = y^x(\ln y)^2 + y'xy^{x-1}\ln y
\\ y'(yx^{y-1}-xy^{x-1}\ln y) & = y^x(\ln y)^2
\\ y' & = \frac{y^x(\ln y)^2} {yx^{y-1}-xy^{x-1}\ln y}
\end{align}

Boas doesn't give the answer as a formula, but with (x,y)=(2,4) plugged in:

$$ y'=4\frac{\ln 2-1}{2\ln 2-1} $$

But that's not at all what I get when I plug in (2,4), so something in my derivation must be wrong. (I compared the two numerically in Mathematica.)

What is wrong? A newbie mistake, or a conceptual misunderstanding.

Comment: I think you've done $\frac{d}{dx}(x^y) = yx^{y-1}y'$ but it [should be this instead](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%28x%5Ey%5Bx%5D%29).

Comment: I think this should be moved to [math.se], but that being said, the problem is in your third line: write $x^y = \exp (y \log{x} )$ and do what you did with the right hand side. Do you get the same answer? If you don't, one of the methods must be wrong. I'll leave it to you to guess which one :)

Comment: On a third line, on the right-hand side, you missed an x.

Comment: @eugenhu, thanks! That fixed it. Now I need to ponder why my initial application of the chain rule didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $x$ and $y$ are variables. You are not justified in claiming $(x^y)' = yx^{y-1}y'$, where you seem to have started off treating $y$ as a constant power, then suddenly changed your mind and multiplied by $y'$ as if remembering it's a variable and introducing chain rule. Instead, use this for the left hand side:

$(x^y)' = (e^{y\ln x})' = (e^{y\ln x})(\frac yx + y'\ln x) = x^y(\frac yx + y'\ln x)$

On the right hand side, you've converted it to an exponential correctly, but you've messed up the chain rule again.

The right hand side should be:

$(y^x)' = (e^{x\ln y})' = (e^{x\ln y})(\frac xy(y') + \ln y) = y^x(\frac xy(y') + \ln y)$

Note that in each case, the chain rule was applied in this form: $(e^w)' = w'e^w$. To compute $w'$, product and chain rules were applied.

I worked with the initial steps you presented to highlight your error. If I were actually doing it myself, I would just take the natural logarithm of both sides before differentiating. It's a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments the derivative
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x^{y(x)}) \stackrel{!}{=} y(x)x^{y(x)-1}y'(x)
$$
does not work. It's not very clear how you got there $-$ it seems that you differentiated $x^y$ with respect to the $x$ in the base as if it had a constant $y$, and then just multiplied by $y'(x)$. To put it simply, that's now how it works.

Things are clearer when you phrase the function as $f(x)=x^{y(x)}$, which makes it more evident that $x$ appears twice. In other words, you need to treat this as a function of the form
$$
f(x)=F(g(x),y(x)) \qquad \text{for} \qquad F(a,b)=a^b,\quad g(x)=x,
$$
so you need to use the chain rule over two variables,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(x)
=
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\frac{\mathrm d a}{\mathrm dx}
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\frac{\mathrm d b}{\mathrm dx}.
$$
You then follow the standard recipes.

---

... or, if you're a bit craftier, you can sidestep a lot of the issues by taking the natural logarithm of your equation to obtain the identity
$$
y(x) \: \ln(x) = x \: \ln(y(x)),
$$
and *then* differentiating.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out your error in computing the derivatives. To make the calculations a bit simpler, consider the following simplification:
$$
x^y = y^x \Leftrightarrow  y \ln x = x \ln y
$$

Now, taking the derivative on both sides

$$
y' \ln x + \frac yx = \ln y + \frac{x y'}{y} \Leftrightarrow y' = \frac{\ln y -\frac yx}{\ln x -\frac xy}.
$$

This last expression is equivalent to the one in Boas.